# Mediawiki mass user delete/merge/block

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, spam, spam-prevention

I have 500 or so spambots and about 5 actual registered users on my wiki. I have used nuke to delete their pages but they just keep reposting. I have spambot registration under control using reCaptcha. Now, I just need a way to delete/block/merge about 500 users at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just delete the accounts from the `user` table manually, or at least disable their authentication info with a query such as:

```sql
UPDATE /*_*/user SET
  user_password    = '',
  user_newpassword = '',
  user_email       = '',
  user_token       = ''
WHERE
  /* condition to select the users you want to nuke */
```

(Replace `/*_*/` with your [`$wgDBprefix`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBprefix), if any.  Oh, and do make a backup first.)

Wiping out the `user_password` and `user_newpassword` fields prevents the user from logging in.  Also wiping out `user_email` prevents them from requesting a new password via email, and wiping out `user_token` drops any active sessions they may have.

---

**Update:** Since I first posted this, I've had further experience of cleaning up large numbers of spam users and content from a MediaWiki installation.  I've documented the method I used (which basically involves first deleting the users from the database, then wiping out up all the now-orphaned revisions, and finally running rebuildall.php to fix the link tables) in [this answer on Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/mass-deletion-of-spam-revisions-in-mediawiki/45486#45486).

---

Alternatively, you might also find [Extension:RegexBlock](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RegexBlock) useful:

> "RegexBlock is an extension that adds special page with the interface for blocking, viewing and unblocking user names and IP addresses using regular expressions."

Comment: Thanks a lot. Deleting the user tables manually worked fine. I'm glad that PHPmyAdmin has a select all button. There were 836 spambots and 5 real users.

Comment: People might find the [Deleteuser](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Deleteuser) extension helpful, to avoid the risk of dangerous mistakes with SQL commands.

Answer (score 3):

There are risks involved in applying the solution in the accepted answer. The approach may damage your database! It incompletely removes users, doing nothing to preserve referential integrity, and will almost certainly cause display errors.

[Here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:UserMerge#Mass_merging.3F_16932) a much better solution is presented (a prerequisite is that you have installed the [User merge extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserMerge)):

> I have a little awkward way to accomplish the bulk merge through a
>   work-around. Hope someone would find it useful! (Must have a little
>   string concatenation skills in spreadsheets; or one may use a python
>   or similar script; or use a text editor with bulk replacement
>   features)
>
> 1. Prepare a list of all SPAMuserIDs, store them in a spreadsheet or textfile. The list may be 
>      prepared from the user creation logs. If you do have the
>      dB access, the Wiki_user table can be imported into a local list.
> 2. The post method used for submitting the Merge & Delete User form (by clicking the button) should be converted to a get method. This
>      will get us a long URL. See the second comment (by Matthew Simoneau)
>      dated 13/Jan/2009) at
>      http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242300
>      for the method.
>      The resulting URL string should be something like below:
>
>    > http: //(Your Wiki domain)/Special:UserMerge?olduser=(OldUserNameHere)&newuser=(NewUserNameHere)&deleteuser=1&token=0d30d8b4033a9a523b9574ccf73abad8%2B\
> 3. Now, divide this URL into four sections:

```
 A: http: //(Your Wiki domain)/Special:UserMerge?olduser= 

 B: (OldUserNameHere) 

 C: &newuser=(NewUserNameHere)&deleteuser=1 

 D: &token=0d30d8b4033a9a523b9574ccf73abad8%2B\
```

> 4. Now using a text editor or spreadsheet, prefix each spam userIDs with part A and Suffix each with Part C and D. Part C will include the
>      NewUser(which is a specially created single dummy userID). The Part D,
>      the Token string is a session-dependent token that will be changed per
>      user per session. So you will need to get a new token every time a new
>      session/batch of work is required.
> 5. With the above step, you should get a long list of URLs, each good to do a Merge&Delete operation for one user. We can now create a
>      simple HTML file, view it and use a batch downloader like DownThemAll
>      in Firefox.
>      Add two more pieces " Linktext" to each line at
>      beginning and end. Also add  at top and  at
>      bottom and save the file as (for eg:) userlist.html
> 6. Open the file in Firefox, use DownThemAll add-on and download all the files! Effectively, you are visiting the Merge&Delete page for
>      each user and clicking the button!
>
> Although this might look a lengthy and tricky job at first, once you
>   follow this method, you can remove tens of thousands of users without
>   much manual efforts.
>
> You can verify if the operation is going well by opening some of the
>   downloaded html files (or by looking through the recent changes in
>   another window).
>
> One advantage is that it does not directly edit the
>   MySQL pages. Nor does it require direct database access.

I did a bit of rewriting to the quoted text, since the original text contains some flaws.

Comment: Actually, the query given in my answer does not delete *any* users (it just disables their auth info so they can't log in), so it will not break referential integrity (not that MediaWiki has ever cared much about that, anyway) and should not cause any display issues (except insofar as your Special:ListUsers will still be filled with spam accounts). That said, I'd no longer recommend that method in most cases; it's much cleaner to [just delete the spam users and their contribs entirely, and then use maintenance scripts to fix the database](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/45486).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, thanks for the link, seems a good solution too.